# Does the sum of reciprocals of primorials converge?

Tags: summation, factorial, primorial

It is well known that the sum

$$
\sum _{{k=0}}^{\infty }{\frac  {x^{k}}{k!}}
$$

converges to $e^{x}$. In particular, for $x=1$ we have $\sum _{{k=0}}^{\infty }{\frac  {1}{k!}}=e$. But what about the sum over the reciprocals of primorials, i.e.,

$$
\sum _{{k=0}}^{\infty }{\frac  {x^{k}}{k\#}},
$$

where $k\#$ denotes the product of all primes equal to or smaller than $k$. Does the sum $\sum _{{k=0}}^{\infty }{\frac  {1}{k\#}}$ converge, like it's factorial analogue does?

In the same spirit, it would also be interesting to ask whether the sum

$$
\sum _{{k=0}}^{\infty }{\frac  {x^{k}}{p_k\#}}
$$

converges, where $p_k\#$ is the product of the first $k$ primes. Unfortunately, I have found no reference to such sums after a quick search on internet. What can be said about these sums?

Comment: Notice that $p_k\#\ge k!$.

Comment: By the prime number theorem and the Cauchy-Hadamard formula, the radius of convergence of $$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k\#}$$ is $e$. Chebyshev's bounds already show the radius of convergence is larger than $e^{0.9}$, so the series clearly converges for $x = 1$. What it converges to is a different kettle of fish.

Answer (score 1):

Far more precisely we use [Chebyshev function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function) $\theta(x) \triangleq \sum_{p \le x} \log p$.

So
$$
(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N^*}} \triangleq\dfrac{1}{n\#}= \dfrac{1}{\prod_{p\leq n} p} = \dfrac{1}{e^{\theta(n)}}
$$

Thus (proof in Hardy's [Introduction to the Theory of Numbers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198531710))

$$ a_n = \dfrac{1}{e^{n+o(n)}}=e^{-n}e^{-o(n)} $$

And radius is given by

$$ R=\dfrac{1}{\limsup(a_n^{\frac{1}{n}})}$$

i.e.

$$ R= e$$

Answer (score 0):

For the second one , D'Alembert criterion is also sufficient there.

Indeed , 
 you have $$ \forall k \in \mathbb{N}^*, \ \frac{x^{k+1}}{p_{k+1}\#}\frac{p_{k}\#}{x^{k}}=\frac{x}{p_k}   $$

which obviously converges to 0.

**Conclusion:**

The second radius is infinite.

Comment: Isn’t D’Alembert’s criterion inconclusive for x = 1 in the first case? You would need the limit superior of the ratios of the terms to be less than one to conclude the series converges, but here the lim sup is 1 when x = 1.

Comment: I modified , it is less or equal to one !

Comment: We can't conclude by this method for x=1